# Acrobat PDF - How to generate unique number when document opens - only if field is blank - using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, user-experience, acrobat

I've signed up specifically to ask this. Have spent a long time researching and have still not solved this.

I have a PDF which I'm editing in Acrobat DC. In this PDF I have a text field (read only) which needs to be filled with a unique number when the PDF is opened. I have done this using:

```
this.getField("Invoice No").value = util.printf("%06d", Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1));
```

When I open the file it generates a number in the correct field, however if I save it (or if I don't), then close and open it again, it generates a new number.

I am not experienced at all with JavaScript but I know there is a simple bit of code I'm missing. In plain english, I want:

"In the event of the document being opened, apply the script to the field - only if the field is empty" I'm hoping this will avoid filling it each time the page is opened when already populated. The user will be opening this as a 'master file' where the field will be empty, but when they open it it will populate, they will save the file, and then have a unique form number.

I hope I've made sense. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by testing whether the field has the same value as its default value, as in:

```
if (this.getField("Invoice No").value == this.getField("Invoice No").defaultValue) {
this.getField("Invoice No").value = util.printf("%06d", Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1));
}
```

And that should do it.

**Update**: If there are doubts about the uniqueness of the number, one could use the current date as base. This could be done like this:

```
var myInvNumber = new Date().getTime() ;
```

As this number is pretty long, and has a long era in the past (in fact, as of now, 37 years worth of milliseconds), one could set an offset, corresponding to an initial date, and subtract it from the number resulting from the above code.

Comment: Do you know if there is a better way to generate the number? I've read that it may be better to generate it based on date with milliseconds, as to avoid the possibility of repeated numbers. If so, would you know how to do it?

Comment: First, you might have to check the regulations whether your invoice numbers must be numbers, and must be in ascending order (you may ask your accountant about that). If not, you could indeed use the Date object in JavaScript (core). Again, I add the code to my answer (as it can be formatted there).